# add data into primary key

Tags: sql, oracle, key, constraints

this is my table.In this table i want to add a primary key column name "emp_id" as the first column .I don't know how to do it .So,can you please help me!

```
EMP_NAME             EMP_POS            SALARY           GENDER 
----------------- ----------------- --------------      ------ 
anand              worker             10000                 M      
balu               manager            50000                 M      
carl               manager            50000                 M      
riya               md                 60000                 F      
prabhu             owner              99999999              M
```

Comment: Hint: Alter command to add a column and then Update with Rownum to populate the data into that column.

Comment: https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/primary_keys.php

Comment: hey,its only there about create table in the link.
but i need to add column to an existing table and it should be primary key.
how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The old way of doing this is a multi-step process:

- add the column which will be the primary key
- update the column
- enforce the primary key.

Something like this:

```
create sequence t23_id;

alter table t23 add id number;

update t23 
set id = t23_id.nextval
;
     
alter table t23 add constraint t23_pk primary key (id);
```

In 12c Oracle added Identity columns (like SQL Server auto-incrementing columns). This reduces the number of steps to two:

```
alter table t23i add id number GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY primary key;

alter table t23i add constraint t23i_pk primary key (id);
```

Unfortunately it can't be done in one step. This ...

```
alter table t23i add id number GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY primary key;
```

...hurls ...

> ORA-01758: table must be empty to add mandatory (NOT NULL) column

[Livesql demo](https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/s/f1k05vod34gloq3u9ae66dspu)

Answer (score -1):

Introduce identity column:
see http://sql-plsql.blogspot.sg/2014/11/add-identity-column-to-table.html

Reorder the columns:
see http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_change_column_order_within_oracle_table.htm

Hope these references help.